# VerifyError when using jacoco coverage on android

Tags: android, code-coverage, android-gradle-plugin

`gradle connectedCheck` works fine  for me only when coverage is executing my POJO objects. When it starts touching mocked object or say, `MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider` is about to be instantiated by test, I'm receiving VerifyError.

```
06-06 13:27:05.664 E/AndroidRuntime( 2443): java.lang.VerifyError:     com/myapp/contentprovider/EthanContentProvider
06-06 13:27:05.664 E/AndroidRuntime( 2443):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-06 13:27:05.664 E/AndroidRuntime( 2443):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
06-06 13:27:05.664 E/AndroidRuntime( 2443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
06-06 13:27:05.664 E/AndroidRuntime( 2443):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
```

After digging deeper, my understanding, that problem is all about trying to match stubbed SDK ContentProvider and real from device's framework.jar.
Jacoco when preprocessing classes, added method pointers into file that it is re-using during execution (.em file).

Any suggestions/ideas?

Sorry about question layout style. Feel free to edit.

Comment: This seems to be a bug/problem with jacoco library, I was facing the same error in a different environment. My current "solution" is to set the visibility of class methods from private to e.g. protected or package. There is also an nice blog post http://www.androidpuzzles.com/168_17620080/ which explains the problem in detail. Another possible solutions seems to be using old JDK1.5.
There is also a bug ticket https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69407

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!!! I did
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
    }
and now I have fully generated coverage report. )))